# Zend_Db Question... updating an incrementor

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Should this work? (increment the login count?)

```
// update the login count
$data = array(
   'logins' => 'logins + 1'
);

$n = $db->update('users', $data, 'user_id = '.$_userId);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = array(
   'logins' => new Zend_Db_Expr('logins + 1')
);
```

Also use quoting so you aren't as vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
$n = $db->update('users', $data, $db->quoteInto('user_id = ?', $_userId));
```

---

Re comment: Yes, in the case of the update() method, it assumes you're sending a literal value unless you use an object of type Zend_Db_Expr.  You can test this yourself:

```
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);
$n = $db->update('users', $data, $db->quoteInto('user_id = ?', $_userId));
$qp = $db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile();
echo $qp->getQuery() . "\n";
```

Any literal value you give in your `$data` array is parameterized so the query ends up looking like this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `login` = ? WHERE user_id = 123
```

If you use an object of class Zend_Db_Expr, it knows to interpolate the string literally into the query, instead of parameterizing:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `login` = NOW() WHERE user_id = 123
```

Note that when you interpolate expressions like this, you are responsible for validation so you don't get security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Would the same go for 'Now()' ?